# Kendo Chart UI refresh the new data with old data

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I've tried to bind my chart with some information, for example a report of 13-01-2014 to 17-01-2014, in the first time that I search the data it's ok in the char, but in the second time the new data add to the old data.

I want to refresh de Chart only with new searchs to the data source.

Here's my Controller

```
public ActionResult GraficoServicio(string txtFechaInicio, string txtFechaFin)
    {
        if (!Convert.ToBoolean(Session["superusuario"]))
        {
            if (!_sesion.VerifarSesion(Convert.ToInt16(Session["id_usuario"]))) { Session["aux"] = 0; Session["Usuario"] = null; Session["id_usuario"] = null; Session["superusuario"] = false; Session["id_empresaUsuario"] = null; Session["Rol"] = null; return View("SesionExpiradaConsultas"); }

            if (!_sesion.VerificarAccionAcceso(Convert.ToInt16(Session["id_usuario"]), "Consultas", "VER", "ControlInterno"))
                return View("AccesoDenegadoConsultas");
        }

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFechaInicio)) txtFechaInicio = "";
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtFechaFin)) txtFechaFin = "";

        ViewBag.Fecha = _FechaSistema.GetFechaSistema();

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult LeerExt_GraficoServicio(string txtFechaInicio, string txtFechaFin)
    {
        return Json(GetServiciosByFecha(txtFechaInicio, txtFechaFin));
    }
```

My View

`@model IEnumerable

Gráfico de servicios por empresa

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart(Model)
.Name("Chart")
.Title("REPORTE DE SERVICIOS POR EMPRESA")
.DataSource(datasource => datasource
    .Read(read => read.Action("LeerExt_GraficoServicio", "Consultas"))
    .Group(group=>group.Add(model => model.TIPO_SERVICIO))
    )
    .SeriesDefaults(seriesDefaults =>
        seriesDefaults.Column().Stack(true)
    )
    .Series(series => {
        series.Column(model => model.TOTAL_HORAS)
            .Name("");
    })
    .Legend(legend => legend
        .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Right)
    )
    .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric()
        .Labels(labels => labels
            .Format("{0}")
            .Skip(1)
            .Step(1)
        )
    )
            .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
                .Categories(model => model.EMPRESA)
                        .Labels(label => label.Rotation(-90))
                        .MajorGridLines(major=>major.Visible(false))
    )
    .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
        .Visible(true)
        .Format("{0,00}")
        .Template("#= series.name #: #= value #")
    )
    )
```

`

JavaScript for Chart

`

```
function BindChart() {
    $("#Chart").data("kendoChart").dataSource.read();
    $("#Chart").data("kendoChart").redraw();
    $("#Chart").data("kendoChart").refresh();
}
```

`

Comment: I havae same problem. Were you able to solve it?

Comment: Hi, Yes I comment the `$("#Chart").data("kendoChart").refresh();` like this:

`function BindChart() {
    $("#Chart").data("kendoChart").dataSource.read();
    $("#Chart").data("kendoChart").redraw();
    //$("#Chart").data("kendoChart").refresh();
}`